# Show that $\hat{Y}$ is an optimal linear estimator of Y

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

**Relevant Information.** Let $X(t)$, $t \in T$ be a second order process. Let $M_0$ be the set of random variables of the form $a + b_1X(s_1)+ \cdots + b_nX(s_n)$ for a positive integer $n$ and constants $a, b_1,\ldots, b_n$. Let $M$ be the set of random variables that are mean square limits of the elements of $M$. $M$ is closed under addition, scalar multiplication, and mean square convergence. Please comment if you need more clarification regarding the set $M$.

**Problem.** Let $\hat{Y} \in M$ satisfy $\mathbf{E}(\hat{Y}-Y)=0$ and $\mathbf{E}[(\hat{Y}-Y)X(t)]=0$. Show that $\hat{Y}$ is an optimal linear estimator of $Y$.

To start, I think that the following theorem would be relevant:

*Theorem*: $\hat{Y} \in M$ is an optimal linear estimator of $Y$ if and only if $\mathbf{E}[(\hat{Y}-Y)Z]=0, Z\in M$

Could someone give me an idea of how to start this problem? I noticed that it follows from the given assumptions that $\mathbf{E}[(\hat{Y}-Y)Z]=0, Z \in M_0$, where we have made $Z$ take on the form $a + b_1X(s_1)+ \cdots + b_nX(s_n)$. I'm not sure how to get from proving this for $Z \in M_0$ to the extension of $Z \in M$.

Comment: You can look up the orthogonality principle (note that in this case, optimality is in the sense of minimum mean square error; if you choose other error criterion, this estimator may not be optimal). You can also find the solution [here](http://hajek.ece.illinois.edu/Papers/randomprocJuly14.pdf) as Theorem 3.2.

Comment: In the same vein, I can see that $(\hat{Y}-Y)$ is orthogonal to all elements of $M_0$ from the assumptions, but it's still unclear to me why it is orthogonal to all elements of $M$.